# Filtering data in datagrid view with multiple comboboxes

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, combobox, filtering

I was trying to create a filter on the `datagridview` using `combobox`. What I wanted to do is to filter the filtered data in the `datagridview`. I already tried some ways that I thought could solve the issue but it does not work. I have five `comboboxes` for the filtration. For example, the first `combobox` is for the Year then I still want to filter the search into Grade level,then to Section and so on. So, the user will be able to sort or filter his search from the database. So far i have my stored procedure code and tried it to the two `combobox`.

Stored procedure dbo.uspYearGradeFilter

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspYearGradeFilter]
    @Year Nvarchar(20),
    @Grade Nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT si.StudentID,SI.Surname,SI.FirstName,SI.MiddleName,si.Gender,si.BirthDay,SI.TelNum,
        Birthday,getdate() AS [Today],
            Datediff(yy,BirthDay,getdate()) -
            CASE
                WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,BirthDay,getdate()),BirthDay)
                >GETDATE() THEN 1
                ELSE 0

            END AS [age]
        FROM StudentInformation SI
        JOIN StudentHistory SH
        ON SI.StudentID = SH.StudentID

        WHERE sh.SchoolYear Like '%'+ @Year+'%' AND sh.levels Like '%'+ @Grade+'%' 
END
```

Stored procedure dbo.uspYearFilter

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspYearFilter]
    @Year Nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


        SELECT si.StudentID,SI.Surname,SI.FirstName,SI.MiddleName,si.Gender,si.BirthDay,SI.TelNum,
        Birthday,getdate() AS [Today],
            Datediff(yy,BirthDay,getdate()) -
            CASE
                WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,BirthDay,getdate()),BirthDay)
                >GETDATE() THEN 1
                ELSE 0

            END AS [age]
        FROM StudentInformation SI
        JOIN StudentHistory SH
        ON SI.StudentID = SH.StudentID
        WHERE sh.SchoolYear Like '%'+ @Year+'%' 

END
```

vb.net code cboYear

```
Private Sub cboYear_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboYear.SelectedIndexChanged
        If cboYear.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspYearFilter", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year ", cboYear.Text)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                dt.Clear()
                da.Fill(dt)
                dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 30
                dgv1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
                dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
                dgv1.Columns(0).Name = "Student ID"
                dgv1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "StudentID"
                dgv1.Columns(1).Name = "Last Name"
                dgv1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "SurName"
                dgv1.Columns(2).Name = "First Name"
                dgv1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "FirstName"
                dgv1.Columns(3).Name = "Middle Name"
                dgv1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "MiddleName"
                dgv1.Columns(4).Name = "Gender"
                dgv1.Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "Gender"
                dgv1.Columns(5).Name = "Birthday"
                dgv1.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "Birthday"
                dgv1.Columns(6).Name = "Age"
                dgv1.Columns(6).DataPropertyName = "Age"
                dgv1.Columns(7).Name = "ContactNumber"
                dgv1.Columns(7).DataPropertyName = "TelNum"
                dgv1.DataSource = dt
            End Using

        ElseIf cboYear.SelectedIndex > 0 And cboGrade.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspYearGradeFilter", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year ", cboYear.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade ", cboGrade.Text)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                dt.Clear()
                da.Fill(dt)
                dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 30
                dgv1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
                dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
                dgv1.Columns(0).Name = "Student ID"
                dgv1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "StudentID"
                dgv1.Columns(1).Name = "Last Name"
                dgv1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "SurName"
                dgv1.Columns(2).Name = "First Name"
                dgv1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "FirstName"
                dgv1.Columns(3).Name = "Middle Name"
                dgv1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "MiddleName"
                dgv1.Columns(4).Name = "Gender"
                dgv1.Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "Gender"
                dgv1.Columns(5).Name = "Birthday"
                dgv1.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "Birthday"
                dgv1.Columns(6).Name = "Age"
                dgv1.Columns(6).DataPropertyName = "Age"
                dgv1.Columns(7).Name = "ContactNumber"
                dgv1.Columns(7).DataPropertyName = "TelNum"
                dgv1.DataSource = dt

            End Using

        End If
```

CboGrade

```
Private Sub cboGrade_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboGrade.SelectedIndexChanged
        If cboYear.SelectedIndex > 0 And cboGrade.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspYearGradeFilter", cn)
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year ", cboYear.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade ", cboGrade.Text)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                dt.Clear()
                da.Fill(dt)
                dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 30
                dgv1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
                dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
                dgv1.Columns(0).Name = "Student ID"
                dgv1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "StudentID"
                dgv1.Columns(1).Name = "Last Name"
                dgv1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "SurName"
                dgv1.Columns(2).Name = "First Name"
                dgv1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "FirstName"
                dgv1.Columns(3).Name = "Middle Name"
                dgv1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "MiddleName"
                dgv1.Columns(4).Name = "Gender"
                dgv1.Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "Gender"
                dgv1.Columns(5).Name = "Birthday"
                dgv1.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "Birthday"
                dgv1.Columns(6).Name = "Age"
                dgv1.Columns(6).DataPropertyName = "Age"
                dgv1.Columns(7).Name = "ContactNumber"
                dgv1.Columns(7).DataPropertyName = "TelNum"
                dgv1.DataSource = dt
            End Using
        ElseIf cboYear.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspYearFilter", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year ", cboYear.Text)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                dt.Clear()
                da.Fill(dt)
                dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 30
                dgv1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
                dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
                dgv1.Columns(0).Name = "Student ID"
                dgv1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "StudentID"
                dgv1.Columns(1).Name = "Last Name"
                dgv1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "SurName"
                dgv1.Columns(2).Name = "First Name"
                dgv1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "FirstName"
                dgv1.Columns(3).Name = "Middle Name"
                dgv1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "MiddleName"
                dgv1.Columns(4).Name = "Gender"
                dgv1.Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "Gender"
                dgv1.Columns(5).Name = "Birthday"
                dgv1.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "Birthday"
                dgv1.Columns(6).Name = "Age"
                dgv1.Columns(6).DataPropertyName = "Age"
                dgv1.Columns(7).Name = "ContactNumber"
                dgv1.Columns(7).DataPropertyName = "TelNum"
                dgv1.DataSource = dt
            End Using
    End If
```

Comment: Why SchoolYear is a textfield? What is the possible outcome of LIKE '%2015%' ?

Comment: @Steve , For example the possible outcome is 2013 -2014, 2015-2016 and so on

Comment: It should help you to simplify your code so you Don't Repeat Yourself. You only need one stored procedure with 5 parameters and you don't need to rebuild the grid on every combo selection.

Comment: @Crowcoder , can you help me to rebuild my code? so that i can have a solid idea on how to deal with this. Thanks

Comment: @DietherSilverious, I'm only on my tablet right now but I'll help when I can if you have not solved it. One question - do you care about data that changed since the user opened the form? If not you don't even need to go back to the database at all.

Comment: @Crowcoder . yes i care about the data when the user opened the form. I'm stuck on this for almost 8 hours. and i Can't move on. I hope you can help me find solution. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't work if you just copy and paste it into your project, but it should be pretty close. Here I have refactored the stored procedure to accept all parameters that might come from the comboboxes. You can follow the same pattern to add any number of additional parameters. 
Each parameter is defaulted to `NULL` so that you can call it from your code without actually adding the `SqlParameter` to the command. This is what you will do if a user has not chosen a value from one or more combos. The `COALESCE` function will use the parameter value if it is not null, otherwise it will just match the database value, effectively turning off the filter for that column.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspStudentFilter]
    @Year Nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @Grade Nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @Other1 Nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @Other2 Nvarchar(20) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT si.StudentID,SI.Surname,SI.FirstName,SI.MiddleName,si.Gender,si.BirthDay,SI.TelNum,
        Birthday,getdate() AS [Today],
            Datediff(yy,BirthDay,getdate()) -
            CASE
                WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,BirthDay,getdate()),BirthDay)
                >GETDATE() THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS [age]
        FROM StudentInformation SI
        INNER JOIN StudentHistory SH
            ON SI.StudentID = SH.StudentID
        WHERE sh.SchoolYear LIKE COALESCE('%'+ @Year+'%', sh.SchoolYear)
            AND sh.Levels LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Grade + '%', sh.Levels)
            AND sh.Other1 LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Other1 + '%', sh.Other1)
            -- etc.. for each filter
END
```

Now, you only need to build the grid one time (unless I missed something and you need different columns per filter choices). Do this in some initialization location, I show here in `Form_Load` but you may want to located it in its own `Sub`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 30
    dgv1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
    dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgv1.Columns(0).Name = "Student ID"
    dgv1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "StudentID"
    dgv1.Columns(1).Name = "Last Name"
    dgv1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "SurName"
    dgv1.Columns(2).Name = "First Name"
    dgv1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "FirstName"
    dgv1.Columns(3).Name = "Middle Name"
    dgv1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "MiddleName"
    'etc...
    'etc.....
End Sub
```

Finally, use one `Sub` to get the data and bind the grid. Simply call this Sub from each combobox selection change event. It will add a `SqlParameter` to the command only if the combo has a selected. Remember the stored procedure can handle not being passed a parameter because it has a default.

```
Private Sub BindGrid()
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("dbo.uspStudentInfo", cn)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        'Add a parameter for all comboboxes but only if a value is selected:

        If cboYear.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim paramYear As New SqlParameter("@Year", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20)
            paramYear.Value = cboYear.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramYear)
        End If

        If cboGrade.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim paramGrade As New SqlParameter("@Grade", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20)
            paramGrade.Value = cboGrade.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramGrade)
        End If

        'Etc, etc...

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgv1.DataSource = dt

    End Using
End Sub
```

Now you have one stored procedure and one place to get and bind the data.

Comment: i follow your instructions but there is an error in BindGrid() when clicking the combox. [Screenshot of error](http://img0.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/22008/2200879095c3e913d4fb905cc8ba62c61c2cdf34.png)

Comment: Thank you so much, Problem solved. I just forgot to put this in my storeprocedure.
`@Year Nvarchar(20)= NULL`

Comment: @DietherSilverious, Cheers